# Using Google Checkout for poker site possible?

Tags: google-checkout

I am totally new to google checkout. Out of curiosity what would be some of the architectures for a poker site using google checkout? On each poker hand played would it be possible to directly move money from the loser's google checkout account to the winner's. Would this even be advisable from a security point of view. What would be the google transaction fee for doing this on every poker hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gambling and betting sites are explicitly prohibited by the Google Checkout content policies. Your account will likely be suspended and you won't be able to pay any winnings:

https://checkout.google.com/support/sell/bin/answer.py?answer=75724

If your site is for entertainment purposes only, i.e. no winnings, you may be able to use Checkout. See for example the Zynga Poker game which uses virtual currency; players pay for the chips, but cannot collect any winnings:

https://plus.google.com/games/498289062763

Answer (score 1):

It is not advisable, you can't send money, and paying hand by hand is expensive. With Google being a US company and poker being illegal in much of the US, you may have your account disabled/seized. You also wouldn't make any interest on whatever funds people have stored on their accounts.

The fees are:

```
Monthly Sales Through Google Checkout    Fees Per Transaction
Less than $3,000                         2.9% + $0.30
$3,000 - $9,999.99                       2.5% + $0.30
$10,000 - $99,999.99                     2.2% + $0.30
$100,000 or more                         1.9% + $0.30
```

Comment: But if I'm not in the US but in Europe would that be a problem. And you're saying that google checkout is purely for charging people money, that there is no way to send money like in paypal?

Comment: Only if you cater to US players or have some other financial connection to the US. I would suggest using a bank account in a country that allows international poker.